# CORS issue when accessing the same resource with GET and POST

Tags: java, spring-mvc, post, get, cors

When accessing a resource with GET I check on the server if the user is logged in and redirect him to an SSO login page on a different server, but on the same domain. This works just fine.
I tried to do the same when the user POSTs the same resource, but now the browser shows me 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'.
Why does it work with GET but not with POST?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similiar issues using Spring Boot and Restful API.

You must include Access-Control-Allow-Origin in your header, example:

```
@RequestMapping("responseHeader")   
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> responseHeaderExample(){
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        String _response = "Hello Word";

return new ResponseEntity<String>(_response, HttpStatus.OK).ok().headers(responseHeaders).body(_response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need verify if your backend already been configured with cors, for GET, POST and other HTTP methods.

My spring config class has this configuration:

For exemple:

```
   @Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token"));
    corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);

    return source;
}
```